# Cannot delete python file after close()

Tags: python

I noticed that it's impossible to delete any file until closing code, where this file is used, even after .close(). I saw similar question in stack overflow, but I still cannot understand the issue.
Will be really thankful, if u show me my problem.

```
import os
with open ("test.txt", "r") as fl:
    print(fl.read())
if fl.closed:
    os.remove("test.txt")
else:
    print("It isn't closed")
```

OR

```
import os
fname = "test.txt"
fl = open(fname)
print(fl.read())
fl.close()
if fl.closed:
    os.remove("test.txt")
else:
    print("It isn't closed")
```

The same error : "PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Ok, guys, it somehow solved by itself with restarting Spyder several times. Thanks and good luck

Comment: Unable to reproduce

Comment: Most likely the file is held open by another program (a text editor?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey you can use `unlink` and use `a+`

```
import os
with open ("test.txt", "a+") as fl:
    print(fl.read())
if fl.closed:
    os.unlink("test.txt")
else:
    print("It isn't closed")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `with` statement you don't need to check whether the file is closed or not. It will automatically close the file even if an error occurs.

**Note:** The `with` statement provides a way for ensuring that a clean-up is always used.

From your question, you can use something like this

```
import os
with open ("test.txt", "r") as fl:
    print(fl.read())
os.remove("test.txt")
```

Comment: Yeah, was aware of "with" statement's function , but I couldn't understand the issue. We can see, that file is closed, but still doesn't let to delete him. Your code also cause the same problem

Comment: @Sanchez just like Błotosmętek said It could be used by another program ( just like a text editor ).